# Задача "Lower Bound"

Tags: python, c++

Есть задача:

> На вход подаются N целых чисел, а также набор из M запросов, каждый из которых — целое число. Ваша задача — для каждого запроса найти количество чисел из исходного набора, меньших заданного в запросе числа. Использовать встроенные функции бинарного поиска запрещено.

Пример:
Ввод:
5
1 5 3 2 1
2
4 3
Вывод:
4 3
Я написал такой код на Python:

```py
def sort(a : list, x):
    L = -1
    R = len(a)
    while R - L > 1:
        M = (R + L) // 2
        if a[M] < x:
            L = M
        else:
            R = M
    return R

n = int(input())
a = sorted(list(map(int, input().split())))
m = int(input())
b = list(map(int, input().split()))
for q in b:
    r = sort(a, q)
    print(r)
```

Он работает отлично.
Вот тот же код на C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int count(vector<int> a, int x)
{
    int l = -1;
    int r = a.size();
    while (r - l > 1)
    {
        int m = (r + l) / 2;
        (a[m] < x ? l : r) = m;
    }
    return r;
}
int main()
{
    int n, m; cin >> n;
    vector<int> a (n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    cin >> m;
    vector<int> b (m);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        cin >> b[i];
    for (int q: b)
        cout << count(a, q) << " ";
}
```

Но он работает слишком медленно.
Прошу, помогите, как можно ускорить работу данного кода на С++?

Comment: `count(vector<int> a` - каждый вызов копирует вектор целиком. Сложность создания копии - линейная. На её фоне двоичный (за логарифм) поиск теряется.

Comment: Согласен с @Stanislav Volodarskiy. Всё, кроме копирования массива в функцию, вроде нормально. Просто передавайте массив в функцию по ссылке - измените объявление функции на `int count(vector<int> &a, int x)`

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл ответ:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int count(vector<int> &a, int x)
{
    int l = -1;
    int r = a.size();
    while (r - l > 1)
    {
        int m = (r + l) / 2;
        (a[m] < x ? l : r) = m;
    }
    return r;
}
int main()
{
    int n, m; cin >> n;
    vector<int> a (n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    cin >> m;
    vector<int> b (m);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        cin >> b[i];
    for (int q: b)
        cout << count(a, q) << " ";
}
```

Comment: Вектор лучше передавать по константной ссылке, а еще лучше - `std::span`. Писать бинарный поиск самому хорошо для тренировки, но на деле лучше использовать (вы не поверите) `std::lower_bound` или `std::partition_point`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, в задании сказано "Использовать встроенные функции бинарного поиска запрещено.".

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Угу, действительно. Не увидел.